# How can I mask a polygon in an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, polygon, mask

I have drawn a polygon on an image and now want to mask it. I just want to see the region inside the polygon and have everything outside be black.

Here is my code for drawing the polygon on the image:

```
i = imread('Vlc1.1.png');
pos = [170 350 290 230 430 230 600 350 170 350];
S = insertShape(i,'Polygon',pos);
imshow(S);
```

And here's the resulting image:

[image]

How can I set everything outside the polygon to black?

Comment: Not duplicates, exactly, but you'll find your answer for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49495337/7328782 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49501465/7328782

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the [`poly2mask`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html) function in the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html) to create a binary mask from your polygon, then set all the pixels outside that mask to 0 (i.e. black) in your image:

```
img = imread('Vlc1.1.png');  % Image data, assumed to be 3D RGB image
pos = [170 350 290 230 430 230 600 350 170 350];  % Pairs of x-y coordinates

bw = ~poly2mask(pos(1:2:end), pos(2:2:end), size(img, 1), size(img, 2));  % 2D mask
bw = repmat(bw, [1 1 size(img, 3)]);  % Replicate the mask to make it 3D
maskimg = img;
maskimg(bw) = 0;
imshow(maskimg);
```

And using a cropped version of your sample image, here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @gnovice.........Appreciate your answer and it helps me a lot....So again thank you so much.

Comment: @jemishmavani: Happy to help! In case you were unaware, you can also [mark an answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Welcome to Stack Overflow!